# No DNS resolution with PIA VPN

Tags: networking, dns, vpn

Working on a headless server, I set up PIA VPN using this guide https://www.privateinternetaccess.com/forum/discussion/18781/how-to-setup-headless-no-gui-cli-only-ubuntu.

```
# openvpn --config pia-nl.conf
```

Seems to work, but DNS resolution is not available.

```
# curl ipecho.net/plain
curl: (6) Could not resolve host: ipecho.net

# curl 146.255.36.1/plain
<!-- pageok -->
<!-- managed by puppet -->
<html>
<pre>pageok</pre>
</html>
```

How can I resolve this?

Answer (score 0):

you can manually change the /etc/resolv.conf file after connecting to the VPN or you can set up one the ovpn files to do it whenever you connect. the trouble with both those is that the resolv.conf file gets overwritted periodically. not figured out how to change it permenantly yet without changing permissions on the resolv.conf so that it cant be overwritten

Comment: Please explain the changes that need to be done.